# How to place input function in center of page?

Tags: python, string, input, centering

I want the user to be able to input their username beside the "username: " at the center but the results always be:

```
                                username:                                        example
```

The "username: " is center which is what I want but the input text "example" is always not beside the "username:"

My code is below:

```
username = input("Username: ".center(165))
```

My desired outcome is:

```
                                               username: example
```

with it being in the center of the page.

Comment: `.left(165//2)`?

Comment: `input("Username: ".rjust(165))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `input("Username: ".center(165))` you create a string of length `165` where "Username: " is placed right at the middle. So you get many spaces to the right of that string.

You want the "Username: " string to be at the right-end of the full string, so you should use [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) instead:

```
username = input("Username: ".rjust(165//2))
```