# Print text from right side

Tags: python, string, left-to-right

May I know how to print text to the right side like:

```
                                                                                 This text is at the extreme right
```

I only know center code is this:

```
print("This text is center".rjust(165//2))
```

Thanks
Edit

str.rjust(165//2) is center text from:

[How to place input function in center of page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462751/how-to-place-input-function-in-center-of-page?noredirect=1#comment128009072_72462751)

Comment: `str.rjust` is used for right side

Comment: `str.center` is for center, compare both of them.

Comment: please go through documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20rjust#bytes.rjust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing well just try to use an int like this

```
print("Centered right".rjust(40, ""))
```

The first value is the amount of space de second is the filling item.

Hope it helps